# pdflatex - printing a black and white PDF

Tags: pdflatex

Before reading, I had like to state that I don't know much about LATEX. I just needed to use 'moderncv' so I am asking this question.

Is there any `pdflatex` switch I can use to produce a black and white PDF document?

Comment: Maybe. Please edit your question and tell us where you see colors in the result.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should know that there's a StackExchange dedicated to [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com). This question would probably have better been put there.

No pdflatex switch. The moderncv class does have a `nocolor` option you could try:

`\documentclass[nocolor]{moderncv}`

But that didn't seem to work for me when using one of the themes the class provides. Looking at the internals of the class, however, I think it might help to put:

```
\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{quotecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{addresscolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectionrectanglecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{sectiontitlecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{footersymbolcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
```

right after `\begin{document}`, and before `\maketitle`. At least for the casual theme... if you're using a different one, tell us which one.